# Python Requests POST and GET from API to get response

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to pointing a python script to an API endpoint. I have the sample code, but it is in PHP. I have no experience in PHP.

Below is the PHP code.

```
<?php
$username = "mta-api-sandbox";
$password = "sandbox-secret-key";

$userPwd = $username . ':' . $password;

#==================================
#1. Get Token
$curl = curl_init();
$url = "https://apisandbox.blibli.com/v2/oauth/token";

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => $url,
  CURLOPT_PORT => 443,
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_USERPWD => $userPwd,
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=client_credentials",
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "accept: application/json",
    "cache-control: no-cache",
    "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  ),
));

$response = json_decode(curl_exec($curl));
$err = curl_error($curl);

curl_close($curl);

if ($err) {
  echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} 
echo "<hr>";
?>

<html>
  <pre style="width: 400px"><?php print_r($response); ?></pre>
</html>
```

And below is my python code.

```
import requests
import json
url_sandBox = 'https://apisandbox.blibli.com/v2/oauth/token'
postFields = {'grant_type':'client_credentials'}
credentials = {'username':'mta-api-sandbox', 'password':'sandbox-secret-key'}
headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','accept':'application/json','cache-control':'no-cache'}
req = requests.request(method='POST',
                       url=url_sandBox,
                       params=postFields,
                       json=credentials,
                       headers=headers)
```

However, the python code did not work. If I print out the req object, the results are as follows.

```
In  [49]: req.json()
Out [49]: {'error': 'unauthorized', 'error_description': 'An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext'}
In  [50]: req.reason
Out [50]: 'Unauthorized'
```

Where did I make mistake? Thanks.

FYI, in the API documentation the success response will be as follows.

```
{ "access_token": "1e1ab274-b8dd-4b21-9323-0d1c85f7091d", "token_type": "bearer", "refresh_token": "0468d301-af86-4482-ba17-144b642e19f5", "expires_in": 86400, "scope": "read write trust" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `username` and `password` are in wrong space:

```
import requests
import json
url_sandBox = 'https://apisandbox.blibli.com/v2/oauth/token'
postFields = {'grant_type':'client_credentials'}
credentials = ('mta-api-sandbox', 'sandbox-secret-key')
headers = {'content-type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded','accept':'application/json','cache-control':'no-cache'}
req = requests.request(method='POST',
                       url=url_sandBox,
                       params=postFields,
                       auth=credentials,
                       headers=headers)
```

This one would work.